# Python - groupby mutiple columns - ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this dataframe which has exactly 2 columns. I need to know the frequency of each pair of data.

[image]

I saw this method in Stack:

`base_plot2 = base_plot.groupby(["pred", col_y]).size()`

However, it doesn't work. I got this issue, and I can't figure why.

`ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length`

Comment: I forgot to comment: col_y = "Rating M"

Comment: This should work , try print the df.columns

Comment: I did it before, it returns Index(['Rating M', 'pred'], dtype='object')

Comment: is this work `base_plot.groupby(["pred","Rating M"]).size()`

Comment: You're a genius!! I forgot that col_y is created like col_y = ['Rating M']

Comment: Would you like me add as an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
 col_y = "Rating M"
 base_plot2 = base_plot.groupby(["pred", col_y]).size()
```

Or

```
 base_plot.groupby(["pred","Rating M"]).size()
```